# Good light debian derivates-distro for VIA C3 processor

Tags: distribution

i would like to install a good distro on a VIA C3 Samuel system.
It would be a light server (with a graphical environment) useful for print server, file server etc.

I've tried to install crunchbang linux but it tell me that my processor not support cx8 and cmov instructions.
So i'm trying Knoppix.. but i still have some problem ... 
Do you know other good lightweight distro debian derivates that support via c3 processor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Debian i386 netinst version works best [according to these notes](http://five.nocrew.org/via/debian.html), but you still have to do some work to get some packages to behave.

http://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/